# openRawResource() throws always a NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, resources, keystore

I want to load a keystore in my Android application. I have copied the key (`truststore.bks`) into the folder `res/raw`.  The SDK from Android generate the R.java with a entry for trustsotre. In the App in try to use: 
`Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);`

But I get always a exception: 
`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040000`

I look into the apk File und saw the truststore.bks file is in the folder`res/raw/`.

What is my misstake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the system level resources with the call to Resources.getSystem. Specifically the documentation states that this does not provide access to application resources. You need to call getResources on a Context object in your application - all your activities are a Context object since they inherit from Context.

Comment: Thanks, it works with `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);`

Answer (score 0):

does your R.java contains corresponding entry for it.....
try deleting R.java and building again....
though I am not completely aware of ur problem....
And this isnt a proper solution as well....

Comment: I've delete the R.java file. After build it new the project contains the entry (in the R.java file). I've also restart eclipse, run the project on another computer. But it doesn't help. I got always the exception